# creating two input block horizontally but it's displaying it vertical

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

//this is the html code that i am using i am  making input buttons horizontally but the problem is that the buttons are not getting displayed correctly.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="lname">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="lastname">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "d-flex" to your class.

Here:

```
 <div class="form-row d-flex">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="fname">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" 
placeholder="First name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="lname">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" 
 placeholder="lastname">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: now how do  i make gap between the two

Comment: You can use margin, padding...

Comment: @AashinSood can you accept the accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

To make a gap between the two you can also use "Justify-Contents-Around"

```
<div class="form-row d-flex justify-content-around ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="lname">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="lastname">
    </div>
</div>
```

Margin and padding would also work!